# Fourier complex exponential series expansion

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have a piecewise function that I need to calculate the complex Fourier series for.

It is for the function $f(x)$ that is 1 on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and zero elsewhere on $[-\pi,\pi]$

I calculated $c_0$ to be 0 and $c_n=\frac{-1}{2\pi in} *e^{inx}\bigg\rvert_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}$

I'm not sure where to go from here, the question also requires me to define the series as g(x) and evaluate $g(3\pi/2)$

Comment: $c_n=\frac{sin(\frac{n\pi}{3})}{n\pi}$.  Also $c_0\ne 0$.